# ASP.NET Web Application not executing code in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net

I inherited an ASP.NET Web Application that was probably built ~10 years ago.  I am using VS 2019 Community.  I am trying to setup log4net's configuration loading in the Application_Start hook of Global.asax.cs.  After much troubleshooting, I discovered none of the code in Global.asax.cs was executing when debugging locally.  I determined this by trying to throw an exception from Application_Start which never happens.  Here's what I've tried so far in rough order:

1) I renamed the old Global and added a new one via the Project->Add_New_Item->Global_Application_Class.  I set each class method to contain only `throw new Exception("wtf");`.  Still, the exceptions don't fire.  The exact code of Global.asax.cs is below.

2) I checked the "Enable Edit and Continue" box under the Project/Web settings.  Still no change.

3) I ensured IIS was stopped, even quit/restarted VS 2019, and restarted my computer.  Cleaned the entire project and rebuilt it.  Still, nothing.

4) I tried switching my real project from ".NET Framework 4" to ".NET Framework 4.7.2".  It did not help.

5) I created a new Web Application project from scratch, added a Global.asax just like I did in #1 above, and **IT WORKS** exactly how I expect it to.  This seems to indicate that my VS/IIS are working.

Since the webapp-from-scratch works fine, it seems to point the finger at something in my real webapp.  I tried grepping around looking for differences between the 2 projects, but came up empty handed.  How does IIS know to execute the Global code?  Is there something else I need to configure in my project so that IIS will execute that code?

**Update 12/07/19.  This is the code for the Global.asax* files:**

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="TM.Website.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace TM.Website
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("wtf");
        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("wtf");
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("wtf");
        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("wtf");
        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("wtf");
        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("wtf");
        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("wtf");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the new class inherit from HttpApplication? You likely can only have one class inherit from HttpApplication, regardless of what it is named, so remove the old one, don't just rename it

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I thought that was going to be it, but alas, it did not make a difference.  I grepped the entire source to ensure there was only a single class inheriting from System.Web.HttpApplication, and it was confirmed.  I also restarted VS and cleaned/rebuilt project for good measure.

Comment: can you show the class? Are you sure it is public?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Yes, it is public.  I just added the source code of both Global.asax* files to the end of my question.

Comment: After more tinkering which included digging into the webapp DLLs via dotPeek, and diffing the applicationhost.config files between the working and broken project, I was at a loss for anything within the project that was causing my problem.  On a whim, I decided to re-clone my git repo to a new location using VS instead of CLI git on WSL and to my surprise, it seems to be working now.  I'm going to try this again in the morning when my eyes/brain are fresh to try to narrow down the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my environment, but I still don't know what's broken.  All I did was re-clone my project to a different location on c: using VS2019's built-in git client.  For some reason, the old directory (which I created via WSL) does not work properly.  I thought that this was due to WSL creating the files/directories differently than the native filesystem, so I set out to try a few different combinations to see what happens.  Note that I did all of the following in order:

0) I let VS2019 create the source/repos/ directory and clone my project into it.  This works fine (my Global hooks run).  This is what is described above.

1) I renamed the source/ directory to source.bak/, created a new source/ using WSL, then copied the project files from #0 over using WSL.  This works fine.

2) I removed the project from the new source/ directory created in #1, and copied it from my old location (scm/).  This did not work (Global hooks don't run).

3) I realized that the project files from a different location may have the old path embedded in some places.  I cleared out all bin/, obj/, and .vs/ directories.  I performed a grep across the project for the old directory, and didn't find anything relating to the old location.  I then ran a `diff -bur` between the working and non-working directories and found no differences except for an empty App_Data folder.  Still, the Global hooks did not run.

As far as I can tell, there is no difference in the content of the files between the working and non-working versions of the project.  There must be some metadata in the non-working files that is causing this problem.